# python Improve a function in a elegant way

Tags: python, optimization, performance

I have a grid as

```
>>> data = np.zeros((3, 5))
>>> data
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]
```

i wrote a function in order to get the ID of each tile.

```
array([[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4)],
      [(1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)],
      [(2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4)]]


def get_IDgrid(nx,ny):
    lstx = list()
    lsty = list()
    lstgrid = list()
    for p in xrange(ny):
        lstx.append([p]*nx)
    for p in xrange(ny):
        lsty.append(range(0,nx))
    for p in xrange(ny):
        lstgrid.extend(zip(lstx[p],lsty[p]))
    return lstgrid
```

where nx is the number of columns and ny the number of rows

```
test = get_IDgrid(5,3)
print test
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

this function will be embed inside a class

```
class Grid(object):
    __slots__= ("xMin","yMax","nx","ny","xDist","yDist","ncell")
    def __init__(self,xMin,yMax,nx,ny,xDist,yDist):
        self.xMin = xMin
        self.yMax = yMax
        self.nx = nx
        self.ny = ny
        self.xDist = xDist
        self.yDist= yDist
        self.ncell = nx*ny
```

Comment: Good question. The only thing I'd suggest is actually having `get_IDgrid` in the class rather than saying that it will be embedded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy has built in functions for most simple tasks like this one. In your case, [`numpy.ndindex`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html) should do the trick:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> [j for j in np.ndindex(3, 5)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4),
 (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

You can get the same result in a similarly compact way using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) :

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [j for j in itertools.product(xrange(3), xrange(5))]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4),
 (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

**EDIT** Note that the (now corrected) order of the parameters is reversed with respect to the OP's `get_IDgrid`.

Both expressions above require a list comprehension, because what gets returned is a generator. You may want to consider whether you really need the whole list of index pairs, or if you could consume them one by one.

Comment: Thanks @jaime. Do you think insert the def of [j for j in np.ndindex(5, 3)] in the class can be correct?

Comment: @Gianni It is kind of hard to tell without knowing what exactly you are trying to accomplish. I can't think of any situation in which I would want to store a list of all possible indices to a numpy array, but if you really do need it, then I guess it is OK.

Comment: @jamie with [j for j in np.ndindex(5, 3)] return a different result respect my function and the Grid (see the example). Just invert the example :)

Comment: @Gianni I did notice that, it is now corrected. What `np.ndindex` does is what is known as [row major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) arrays, which is the standard in C language, and the default in numpy. What your function is doing is column major order, which is the Fortran and Matlab way. If you are using numpy, it will probably make your life easier if you stick to row major.